# Change background color in App delegate

Tags: ios, background, ios7, uicolor

I cant seem to change the color of the background of all views in the app delegate.

In ios6 this worked:

```
window.backgroundColor =[UIColor blueColor];
```

and be setting the background to clear in each UIView.

But this doesnt work in iOS7 for some reason. I can set the color of the background in each view no problem but this is a lot of work, there must be an easier way? Any advice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a terrible way to change the background color! If anything is moving, the animations will slow down from all the transparency. Change the view's `backgroundColor` in each view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Comment: @Abizern Thank you! The old me would have done it in `init`, but the new me has read the VC PG.

Comment: @nevanking Thanks, I never saw any problem doing that way before. I saw a solution online, might have been here.

Comment: @Gman The general rule is if you can make views opaque, it's better. Less compositing (layering together views). It takes ages to learn view controllers though, just keep plugging away.

Comment: @nevanking I really appreciate the heads up!! :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why this is a lot of work, it's just setting a property when you create the view.

and having all your views transparent so that you only need to set the colour of your window is a terrible performance hit. Transparent views need to show the views underneath them and this increases the processor load.

You are really better off setting the background colour of your views and keeping them opaque.

Comment: I was just looking for a quick fix, I never knew it would lead to such issues setting the background in App delegate...thanks for the advice!